# Increase executor queue size in CXF OneWayProcessorInterceptor

Tags: java, web-services, configuration, cxf

I got the following warnings and then a NPE with a service created with CXF (2.5.2) that runs on Jetty. Does someone know how to increase the executor queue size as suggested in the warning?

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OneWayProcessorInterceptor handleMessage
WARNING: Executor queue is full, run the oneway invocation task in
caller thread. Users can specify a larger executor queue to avoid
this.

WARNING: Interceptor for
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/bw-2}MyPublishService#{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/bw-2}Notify
has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WrappedMessageContext.<init>(WrappedMessageContext.java:107)
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:53)
       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
       at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:232)
       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OneWayProcessorInterceptor.handleMessage(OneWayProcessorInterceptor.java:143)
       ...
```

**Update**: Thanks to accepted answer I have created a xml file that contains the following spring bean:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="cxf.default.workqueue" class="org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl">
        <property name="name" value="default" />
        <property name="queueSize" value="512" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Can you tell me the location at which you copied the bean configuration file and the corresponding configurations in the deployment descriptors to read this file?

Comment: You just have to create a file (e.g. cxf.xml) with the right content and to add it inside your classpath.

Comment: Yea I figured that out. Added it to my beans.xml file which is also used for publishing my Web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easily configurable (you would need to register your own instance of `AutomaticWorkQueue` into the bus for the application). The default value for the max number of threads processing `@OneWay` invocations is 256, meaning the server can serve up to 256 simultaneous `@OneWay` requests without blocking the caller thread.

In your case, You may create a spring bean of type `org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl` having a property `name="default"` & set queue size & initial number of threads , high & low range as per the specification http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-core/2.1.4/org/apache/cxf/workqueue/AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java

Comment: @Laurent +1 for the clarification on the server/container details[Jetty], which you have updated in your question.

Comment: Hi for your first suggestion, how to do it? Do you have any reference on how to implement it? I had a problem where my outbound-response is being blocked because the workque is being used by my outbound-client-request. Basically I am also doing an outbound request to external entity. And I have an endpoint that also receives request. They both share the same AutomaticWorkQueue. Is my understanding correct? That is the only reason I could find , on why my response is taking too long even though I'm finished processing it.

Comment: 256 is the default queue size. The default max number of threads is 25. See here https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/workqueue/AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java#L96